# Restrict image upload size

Tags: javascript

How to restrict image upload size 100kb to 2 MB

```
<form id="formId" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fanbook/index/fanbook') ?>" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload" onsubmit="return checkFile();">
          <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>">

        <div id="upload-file-container">
            <input id="img" type="file" name="img">
        </div> 
            <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit" onClick="getSize();">
    </form>
```

Comment: File size should be 0kb to 2Mb

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: <form action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    Upload image:
    <input id="image-file" type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#image-file').bind('change', function() {
            alert('This file size is: ' + this.files[0].size/1024/1024 + "MB");
        });
    </script>

</form>

Comment: what is `getSize()` ?

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake